# Service gets force closed by clean app

Tags: android, service, forceclose

I've developed an app that is mainly a service which does its job very well, on almost all devices, except for the ones that use OneClean app. For an unknown reason this app manages to force close my service and it cannot be restarted using an alarm in `onCreate` or `START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY` in `onStartCommand`. Not even the `BootStartup` Broadcast receiver won't  do the work.
However apps like Whatsapp or Facebook aren't getting tempered with. 
Any idea how I can make my app ignore this apps force close?
Also the app cannot be configured or uninstalled from the device, I cannot even find it with adb, it's just a widget which came with the phone.
Thanks

I've managed to keep the service up, using `BIND_IMPORTANT`, however in the "running screen" it says 0 processes, 1 service at my app. And basically the service isn't doing its job.

Comment: Do you see any log that can help us find the problem?

Comment: nope, it basically force closes apps. The interesting thing is that some, like the ones mentioned earlier are spared. I don't know if there is a list of them or there's something in their code that prevents the force close from code. I've tried it on some of my apps published on Play and it still got closed. So it's not just the case for debugging state apps. Even apps approved by google play get force closed.